# Postgres - autovacuum questions

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I have a couple of questions about autovacuum:

1. Is it safe to turn of vacuuming before a long process of loading/updating data or big queries?
2. What are the recommended configurations for autovacuum?

Comment: 1. From [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-vacuum.html): Plain VACUUM (without FULL) ...  can operate in parallel with normal reading and writing of the table, as an exclusive lock is not obtained.  VACUUM FULL ... requires an exclusive lock

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1: Yes, it is safe, but you need to restart PostgreSQL to change the `autovacuum` setting.

Ad 2: It is recommended that you stick with the default values. If you notice that autovacuum cannot keep up, consider raising `autovacuum_max_workers` and `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit`.